# Establishing relationships through a common table the right way

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have three tables inside of a database: `interest`, `subscription` and `subscriber`. The schema looks like this:

[image: Subscribr Database schema]

The subscription table has a one to many relationship on both interest and subscriber. How I would like it to work, and I'm not sure if how I want it to work and how it's actually working are lining up, but it should be like this: **a Subscriber can have multiple Interests, and each Interest can have multiple Subscribers. This will allow me to see which interests a subscriber has, and which interests have been subscribed to. Then, the Subscription relates only to one subscriber and one interest.** I think that's how it's set up, but I just did some tests querying the subscription table and I got this back:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\public_html\playground\subscribr>php list_subscriptions.php
-testemail@tester.com
--Magazine
-testemail@tester.com
--Newsletter
-testemail@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail@tester.com
--Email
-testemail2@tester.com
--Magazine
-testemail2@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail3@tester.com
--Newsletter
-testemail3@tester.com
--Email
-testemail4@tester.com
--Magazine
-testemail4@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail4@tester.com
--Email
-testemail5@tester.com
--Magazine
-testemail6@tester.com
--Newsletter
-testemail7@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail9@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail10@tester.com
--Newsletter
```

I suppose I expected a result more like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\www\public_html\playground\subscribr>php list_subscriptions.php
-testemail@tester.com
--Magazine
--Newsletter
--Promotions
--Email
-testemail2@tester.com
--Magazine
--Promotions
-testemail3@tester.com
--Newsletter
--Email
-testemail4@tester.com
--Magazine
--Promotions
--Email
-testemail5@tester.com
--Magazine
-testemail6@tester.com
--Newsletter
-testemail7@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail9@tester.com
--Promotions
-testemail10@tester.com
--Newsletter
```

I do get this result if I query by subscriber, and grab their interests (through the subscription table). I'm using ORM, so the code to do that looks like this:

```
$subscriberRepo = $entityManager->getRepository( 'Subscribr\Entity\Subscriber' );
$subscribers = $subscriberRepo->findAll();

foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
    echo sprintf( "-%s\n", $subscriber->getEmail() );
    foreach ($subscriber->getInterests() as $interest) {
        echo sprintf( "--%s\n", $interest->getInterest()->getName() );
    }
}
```

So I can get a subscriber's subscriptions, and interests that are subscribed to, using this schema, but then is there a point in keeping the subscription table around? Or does the whole thing need to be reworked to do what I'd like it to do? I like the having an indirect relationship between subscriber and interests, incase I wanted to add extra columns to the subscription table like removing `is_subscribed` from the subscriber table and adding a column in subscription called `subscription_status`, in that way this solution feels the cleanest. However, it also almost feels like a join table with extra fields. Thoughts?

Comment: The subscription table *is* a join table with extra fields. So what? That is how you represent a many:many binary relationship with attributes. Moreover, it is *how* you are able to "get a subscriber's subscriptions, and interests that are subscribed to". The ORM uses it to implement getInterests().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation a could understand properly what you need to map. In a simplified way you have two options:

**Option 1**

`Subscriber` 1 -> n `Subscription`
`Subscription` n <- 1 `Interest`

It means indirectly: `Subscriber` n -> n `Interest`
Don't see? Lets code to see better:

```
foreach ($subscribers as $subscriber) {
   echo sprintf( "-%s\n", $subscriber->getEmail() );
   foreach ($subscriber->getSubscriptions() as $subscription) {
      echo sprintf( "--%s\n", $subscription->getInterest()->getName() );
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

The above code will work with the below changes in your mapping. This code explanation: Iterate subscribers where each subscriber has a list of subscriptions and each subscription referes on interest.

**Subscriber.php**

```
 /**
  * @var array
  * 
  * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Subscription", mappedBy="subscriber",    cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
  */
  private $subscriptions;
```

You should remove `private $interests;` from `Subscriber`. It won't access `Interest` directly.

**Subscription.php**

```
/**
 * @var Interest
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Interest", inversedBy="subscribers")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="interest_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
private $interest;
```

Notice each `Subscription` will access a single `Interest`.

This first option is the best in your case.

**Option 2**

You could remove `Subscription` class and use its table as a reference table. And map directly: `Subscriber` n -> n `Interest`.

```
class Subscriber {

     /**
      * @var array
      * 
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Interest", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
      * @ORM\JoinTable(name="subscription",
      *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="subscriber_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
      *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="interest_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
      *      )
      */
      private $interests;
}
```

The issue in this option you cannot use `subscription.interest_date` 'cause `subscription` table is now only a relation table. More explanation about that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542243/doctrine2-best-way-to-handle-many-to-many-with-extra-columns-in-reference-table).

Comment: According to the schema I posted, it seems like I already have Option 1. Or is there something I'm missing... which is entirely possible.

Comment: Yes. But notice `Subscriber` access `Subscriptions` and each `Subscription` acess one `Interest`.  Because of that Option 1 code is a little bit different from your code. I edit to include the mapping code in Option 1.